# DataTables - Checkbox Selection - pagination does not retain the values of the selected checkboxes

Tags: pagination, datatables

I'm using jQuery datatables on a table which contains two fields:
a. image names
b. image size

The first column of the table (image names) contain checkboxes for selection which I have added using html. The data in the table is updated from a textfile.

There is a button called make image set. The user should be able to select multiple images and click on the make image set button, which will show a modal with the selected image names. The user can then enter a set name and submit.

However, the problem now is that when datatables pagination takes place, the string which gets the image names (that is displayed on the modal box) only contains the image name of the current page. For example, if I select 2 images from the first page and 2 from the second and if I'm on the second page when I press the "Make image set" button, only the last two image names are displayed in the modal box.

Is there a way in which I can retain the selection of the checkboxes in order to ensure correct selection display on the modal?

The Javascript Code:

```
        var cellsSelected="";
$(document).ready(function() {
var dataTable = $('#table_id').DataTable( {
    columnDefs: [ {
        orderable: false,
        className: 'select-checkbox',
        targets:   0
    } ],
    select: {
        style:    'multi',
        selector: 'td:first-child'
    },
    lengthMenu: [[5,10, 25, -1], [5, 10, 25, "All"]],
    pageLength: 5 
} );
          $('checkboxed').on('click', function() {
    cellsSelected = dataTable.rows({ selected: true }).data();
});

            $('#settable_id').dataTable({
    "lengthMenu": [[5,10, 25, -1], [5, 10, 25, "All"]],
        "pageLength": 5
});
} );
```

The HTML Code:

```
<table id="table_id" class="table table-responsive table-bordered table-condensed">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th colspan= "2" class="text-center"><span style="color:white;" aria-hidden="true"><font size="3"><strong>Image & SMU Repository </strong></font></span>
</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class="text-center verticalalign" style="vertical-align: middle; background-color: #98b6d9;"><span style="color: black;" aria-hidden="true"><strong>Image Name</strong></span></td>
         <td class="text-center verticalalign" style="vertical-align: middle; background-color: #98b6d9;"><span style="color: black;" aria-hidden="true"><strong>File Size</strong></span></td>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <form role="form" id="myForm" method="post">
         <div class="form-group">
            <?php $first1 = ""; $second1 = "";$str = 'size';$a=0;$mylines = file('./view_images.txt');foreach($mylines as $myline){$first1 = $second1;$second1 = $myline;$str1 = (string)$second1;if($a == 1){$sizeChunks = explode(",", $second1); ?>
            <td style="vertical-align: middle;"><span style="color:black;"><a href="./Repository.php" title="MD5 = <?php echo $sizeChunks[1] ?> " class="myClass"><?php echo preg_replace('~\D~', '', $sizeChunks[0]); ?></a></span></td>
            <?php $a=0;continue;}if($first1 == "" or $first1 == "\n"){?>
            <tr>
               <td style="vertical-align: middle;" >
                  <div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" id="checkboxed" name="myCheck" value="<?php echo $second1; ?>"><span style="color:black;"><?php echo trim($second1); ?></span></label></div>
               </td>
               <?php }else{if($second1 == "\n"){?> 
            </tr>
               <?php } else{if(strcmp(trim($str1), trim($str)) == 0){ $a=1;continue;}?>
            <td style="vertical-align: middle;"><span style="color:black;"><?php echo trim($second1); ?></span></td>
            <?php }}}?>
         </div>
      </form>
   </tbody>
</table>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title"><span style="color:black;" aria-hidden="true"></span>Create Image Sets</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body" id="imgmodal">
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submitimgset"><span style="color:black;" aria-hidden="true"></span>Submit</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal"><span style="color:black;" aria-hidden="true></span>Cancel</button>
</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The make image set button -

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" data-target="#myModal" id="make_image_set_id" onclick="imagesumrep()"><span style="color:black;" aria-hidden="true"></span>Make Image Set</button>
```

The Javascript function for the button -

```
function imagesumrep() {
            if(cellsSelected == ""){
                document.getElementById('imgmodal').innerHTML= "Error! <br> Please select images and try again!";

                                  $('#myModal').modal('show'); 

            }
            else{   
            document.getElementById('imgmodal').innerHTML= "<h4><strong><u>Images Selected:</u></strong></h4>" + "<strong>" + cellsSelected + "</strong> "+ "<br /><br />"+ "<h4><strong><u>Image Set Name:</u></strong></h4>" + "<input type ='text' name='setName' id='noname' size='70'><br /><br />";
            setTimeout(function(){
                                  $('#myModal').modal('show'); 
                              }, 600); 
           }
           }
```

Please help me! I'm totally new to DataTables! I've made changes as suggested by Adam. Now, the modal box is not opening at all and I'm getting an error - "Uncaught ReferenceError: dataTable is not defined".

The scripts I've included are:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.0/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.12/sorting/num-html.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.0/css/select.dataTables.min.css" />

<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Datatables is not aware of HTML changes that are made within its cells, but rather is only aware if you update it using the [cell().data()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/cell().data()) method. The unshown items during pagination are not displayed in the DOM, so finding them through conventional means won't work. You'll have to collect the data via dataTables API.

Fortunately, it looks like they've built in basically what you need with the [checkbox example](https://datatables.net/extensions/select/examples/initialisation/checkbox.html) in their documentation. Note that this uses the [select extension](https://datatables.net/extensions/select/), and you'll want the multiselect option. But, assuming you have select downloaded and included, your initialization would end up looking something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var dataTable = $('#table_id').DataTable( {
        columnDefs: [ {
            orderable: false,
            className: 'select-checkbox',
            targets:   0
        } ],
        select: {
            style:    'multi',
            selector: 'td:first-child'
        },
        lengthMenu: [[5,10, 25, -1], [5, 10, 25, "All"]],
        pageLength: 5 
    } );
} );
```

When you want to get your selected items (this is pulled from a [dataTables example](https://datatables.net/extensions/select/examples/api/get.html) as well):

```
var dataSelected = dataTable.rows({ selected: true }).data();
```

This will return an array of data from the dataTable for each row selected, which you can use in your imagesumrep() function.

I made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ootjavc/1/) to try this out if you want to use it as a base

Comment: Hi Adam! Thank you so much for your help. I tried implementing as you suggested but I'm still making some mistake. I've updated the question with the new code and I've also added included the scripts that I've included in my code. Thanks again :)

Comment: Hey Shruti. I forgot to include the variable that will hold the dataTable in my code. I'll update it

Comment: Adam, where you said " $('input').on('click', function () {... "

Should I replace "input" with the id of the button " Make image set" that needs to use this data?

Comment: Yes, the ID or another jquery selector that would work for your case. "input" was just to be a placeholder to show you the idea - for my quick test, if you click on the search bar it triggers the function. I was too lazy to make a button :)

Comment: I've updated the jsfiddle link to include a button now, it might make it clearer for you. The button is just a way to trigger the code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the help, Adam! I'm so lost and I've been stuck with this problem for weeks now.

Comment: I've edited my code in the question. 
Random checkboxes are now appearing on the screen in the middle of the table. And when I select the checkboxes (that I have added) - I get the error modal instead of the modal with the image names.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with php, but it looks like you are still creating your own checkboxes on top of the ones that datatables creates with this plugin. The idea here would be that you are no longer creating your own checkboxes but instead changing it to use datatables select extension to do that part for you.

Comment: Okay! Got it :) Let me try this and get back to you. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Adam, If I do a "document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = cellsSelected;"

The result is "[object Object]". I get the same output if I do "alert(cellsSelected)".
What does this mean? How I get the data value of the selected checkbox? The output using Console.log is displaying something like "Object { context: Array[1], length: 4, selector: Object, tables: r.extend/g/<(), table: r.extend/g/<(), draw: r.extend/g/<(), page: r.extend/g/<(), ajax: Object, rows: r.extend/g/<(), row: r.extend/g/<(), 22 more… }". How do I retrieve the data from this? Sorry for asking you so many questions. :(